# Android Recyclerview nested scrolling vertically and horizontally

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I am currently working for a company and my task it to make a timeline like the picture below. This timeline needs to be scrolled both vertically and horizontally. I am familiar with using recycler views but now I need to nest two recycler views in each other.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I saved your qiustain .. i will answer your quistain afetr search.. be cool

Comment: thank you :) I will be waiting for ur reply cheers